# How do I make a random fact command in my discord bot (DiscordJS)

Tags: javascript, random, discord, bots

So i want it to be like i say `;fact` and the bot responds with a random fact in an embed or something.
Also, does anyone know any alternative to no-api-key since i think it got shut down or something

I tried using api ninjas but it didnt work :crie:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First off, **what version of discord.js are you using?** I am guessing you are using v14, if you are, I would recommend using slash commands as they are more efficient and you can use separate files, not just one.

To make the random fact command, you would probably make a list of facts and then choose one randomly, then send it to the channel the command was sent in.

**Here is some sample code for the randomizer which you can try to implement.**
(Keep in mind that this uses a slash command, and may require you to restart your whole project)

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require(`@discordjs/builders`);
const { EmbedBuilder } = require(`discord.js`);

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("fact")
    .setDescription("Generates a random fact"),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        let facts = ['Fact 1', 'Fact 2', 'Fact 3', 'Fact 4', 'Fact 5']

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('Blue')
        .setTitle('Fact')
        .setDescription(facts[Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length)]) // chooses a random fact from the list

        await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]})
        
    }
}
```

When you do the /fact command, it should generate an embed with the title "Fact" and the random fact.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: now the thing is, im not actually using the slash commands in my bot, its really kind of a small bot for my ict project but now im planning to make it larger, just for instance the bot itself like the code isnt really mine my friend made like 90% of it and gave it to me (its really just like 20 commands or sum) and im tryna add more commands, this is how a "hug" commands is, even tho it doesnt work

Comment: const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
 name: 'hug',
 category: 'extra',
 run: async (client, message, args) => {
  const url = 'https://no-api-key.com/api/v1/hug';

hug command btw

Comment: let response;
  try {
   const { data } = await axios.get(url);
   response = data;
  } catch (e) {
   return message.channel.send('An error occured!');
  }

  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle(`@${message.author.username} hugs @${message.mentions.users.first().username || message.mentions.members.first()}`)
   .setImage(response.link);

  return message.channel.send(embed);
 },

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for API's which gives you random facts for free and its available for public you have a look at [public-apis repository](https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis)

You have a lot of fact apis there some are restricted to particular domain but others open to everything.

You can take everything and do a random to get a fact from a random source for example

The below example is only the JavaScript Example

```js
// Let us take we have 10 different sources to fetch from.
const source = ~~(Math.random() * 10); // Gets a random number.

let fact = "";

switch (source) {
  case 0:
      // Implement to fetch and save fact in some variable
      fact = somecode;
      break;
  case 1:
      // Implement to fetch and save fact in some variable
      fact = somecode;
      break;
  //...other cases till 9
}

// send to a discord channel the way you want embed, text or interaction or anything
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT!!! i thought you were using python (discord.py/py-cord)
but you're using discord.js so the code won't work

make a list of facts and then select one:

```py
# for the list:
facts = ["fact 1", "fact 2"...]

# for the select random you need to
import random

# and then
random.choice(facts)
# will output a random fact
```

for example:

```py
import random

# just copied some random facts from google

facts = [
            "The tree of Coffea arabica will grow fruits after three to five years, and will produce for about 50 to 60 years (although up to 100 years is possible). The white flowers are highly scented. The fruit takes about 9 months to ripen.",
            "A human has a much lower biting pressure of 300 pounds per square inch. Wolves will travel for long distances by trotting at about five miles per hour. They can run at speeds of 25 to 35 miles per hour for short bursts while chasing prey. Wolves may travel 10 to 30 miles each day in search of food.",
            "Vassilyev and his first wife, whose name is unknown, hold the record for the most children a couple has parented. She gave birth to a total of 69 children – sixteen pairs of twins, seven sets of triplets and four sets of quadruplets – between 1725 and 1765, in a total of 27 births."
            ]
            
print(random.choice(facts)) # will print a random fact
```

Comment: If it will not work because written with other language, you should delete your answer